# Apollo runscript failing on iOS?

Tags: apollo, apollo-ios

Running the iOS runscript causes the following error. Any advice?

This happens to the sample project

```
    /bin/sh -c /Users/aryan.ghassemi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrontPage-djowwaikrpnoghhjhlxriwamylsv/Build/Intermediates/FrontPage.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FrontPage.build/Script-9F672F2E1DB0053600974171.sh

/Users/aryan.ghassemi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/lib/cli.js:41
                const [name, value] = header.split(/\s*:\s*/);
                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
The version of Apollo.framework in your project requires apollo-codegen 0.15, but an unknown older version seems to be installed. Installing...
/Users/aryan.ghassemi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/bin/apollo-codegen -> /Users/aryan.ghassemi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/lib/cli.js
+ apollo-codegen@0.15.2
updated 1 package in 1.363s
++ exec apollo-codegen generate ./PostListViewController.graphql ./PostTableViewCell.graphql --schema schema.json --output API.swift
/Users/aryan.ghassemi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/lib/cli.js:41
                const [name, value] = header.split(/\s*:\s*/);
                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script was running on an older version of node, updating to 6.9 fixed the issue